# My attempts to use rsyslog to route messages to a log file

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

In myapp.service, I have :

```
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardErr=syslog
```

When I do :

```
$ journalctl -e -u myapp
```

I can see each line of log contains "myapp[PID]".

I've tried to set up /etc/rsyslog.d/myapp.conf with :

```
if $msg contains 'myapp' then /opt/myapp/log/myapp.log
& stop
```

or

```
if $programname == 'myapp' then /opt/myapp/log/myapp.log
& stop
```

Each time checking syntax with "rsyslogd -N1" and restarting rsyslogd.

But log message is not routed, nothing is written in myapp.log

Could it be because of my rsyslog version (8.16) ? or some permission issue ? I've tried to touch the log file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It was some permission issues: `chmod 666 myapp.log` fixed it.